# 7z cant extract files of a .zip packed with ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, zip

I wrote a programm which zips some files together, for the zipping I am using this command:

```
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(My.Settings.UploadTemp, filename)
```

But the Problem is everytime I try to extract the images with 7z I get an error.

```
unsupported compression method
```

But with the standard Windows 7 archive tool everthing works.

EDIT:
I found a workaround for my Problem.

```
Dim zipper As ZipArchive = ZipFile.Open(Path, ZipArchiveMode.Create)
zipper.CreateEntryFromFile(...)
```

works greate

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it seems to work. Which version of 7zip are you using? Can you try to install the latest one?

Regards,
Ivan Ivanov

Comment: Link is not available